# How to pass paramters to Bokeh server embedded as a library

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a parameter to a function called by the embedded bokeh server. I'm following the [example here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library)
specifically the `standalone_embed.py`. I need to pass a parameter say var from the main function to `modify_doc`. I'm not sure how to do that since the [FunctionHandler](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/application/handlers/function.html)  does not seem to take any parameters.

```
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.server.server import Server

from bokeh.sampledata.sea_surface_temperature import sea_surface_temperature

def modify_doc(doc, var):
    df = sea_surface_temperature.copy()
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
    print var

    plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=(0, 25), y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
                  title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43")
    plot.line('time', 'temperature', source=source)
    doc.add_root(column(plot))

    return doc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    var =5
    server = Server({'/': Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))})
    server.start()

    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    server.io_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.partial` to bind specific values:

```
from functools import partial

server = Server({'/': partial(modify_doc, var=var)})
```

Also note that in more recent versions you can just pas the function itself, as a convenience, and not have to create the `Application` or `FunctionHandler` yourself.

It would also be possible to pass HTML request args when you `show` the page, and have the `modify_doc` app code [inspect those HTML args](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#accessing-the-http-request).